# Asp.Net MVC prevent duplicate records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I prevent a duplicate input in mvc c#?
My primary key is "Locatie"

My code (controller):

```
// GET: Parts/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Parts/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "NaamComponent,Locatie,Waarde,Bestelnummer,ManufacturerPN,Omschrijving")] Parts parts)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Parts.Add(parts);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(parts);
    }
```

Comment: You can disable a button which is causing the HTTP request so it won't fire twice

Comment: You should try to check if part with your `Locatie` value already exists in database. Something like: `if (!db.Parts.Any(part => part.Locatie == parts.Locatie)) { db.Parts.Add(parts); db.SaveChanges(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "NaamComponent,Locatie,Waarde,Bestelnummer,ManufacturerPN,Omschrijving")] Parts parts)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            if (db.Parts.Any(part => part.Locatie == parts.Locatie))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Locatie naam is bezet.");
            }
            else
            {
                db.Parts.Add(parts);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

        return View(parts);
         
    }
```